# How to redirect tun SSL VPN through HTTP CONNECT proxy, using iptables?

Tags: iptables, routing, vpn, android, http-proxy

I use a VPN under SSL solution (Firepass) on Android. VPN opens an SSL connection on port `443` of remote VPN server.

My mobile carrier doesn't allow direct connections on port `443` but allow SSL connections through its HTTP CONNECT proxy.

I want to implement this scenario.

- `tun0` outgoing traffic on VPN server TCP port `443` should be redirected, via `iptables`, on another port on `lo`.
- `redsocks` listening on this port, configured in order to **redirect** connection on HTTP CONNECT proxy.

Also IP address of HTTP proxy server should be routed on `rmnet0` network interface and other traffic on `tun0`.

Comment: ATM, I have configured redsocks in order to do http-connect and listening on port 8124. I have a rule like this: `iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8124`. VPN client login and VPN starts but I see only packet transmitted and none received.

Comment: You have to configure the VPN end point somewhere, don't you? Why not simply change that to the redsocks port? Redirection from real interfaces to `lo` is not easily possible. If you cannot change the configuration: Would it be OK to run redsocks on a normal interface, limit its accessibility with `iptables` and redirect the traffic there?

Comment: @hauke-laging I can't change VPN configuration. I can bind `redsocks` on 0.0.0.0 but I can't `REDIRECT` with `iptables` (redirection works only on local addresses). Investigating with `netstat` I see tcp connection to VPN server in `ENSTABILISHED` state but I can't receive back any packet from `tun0`

Comment: @osidovich Sorry, `REDIRECT` is not affected by this problem, no need to change to `0.0.0.0`. Can you inspect the traffic on the other side of the tunnel?

Comment: @hauke-laging No, I can't inspect the traffic on the other side of the tunnel